# How to find the nearest neighbors of 1 Billion records with Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, nearest-neighbor, euclidean-distance

Given 1 Billion records containing following information:

```
    ID  x1  x2  x3  ... x100
    1   0.1  0.12  1.3  ... -2.00
    2   -1   1.2    2   ... 3
    ...
```

For each ID above, I want to find the top 10 closest IDs, based on Euclidean distance of their vectors (x1, x2, ..., x100).

What's the best way to compute this?

Comment: What have you tried? We ask that you show us what you have tried so far, and when you get stuck or don't understand an error and the documentation can't help, we will be here to try. Also, it is important to include sample data that is easy for other users to copy and paste into their own environment, so they can follow along in their own environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Performing a brute-force comparison of all records against all records is a losing battle. My suggestion would be to go for a ready-made implementation of k-Nearest Neighbor algorithm such as the one provided by `scikit-learn` then broadcast the resulting arrays of indices and distances and go further.

Steps in this case would be:

1- vectorize the features as Bryce suggested and let your vectorizing method return a list (or numpy array) of floats with as many elements as your features

2- fit your scikit-learn nn to your data:

```
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=10, algorithm='auto').fit(vectorized_data)
```

3- run the trained algorithm on your vectorized data (training and query data are the same in your case)

```
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(qpa)
```

Steps 2 and 3 will run on your pyspark node and are not parallelizable in this case. You will need to have enough memory on this node. In my case with 1.5 Million records and 4 features, it took a second or two.

Until we get a good implementation of NN for spark I guess we would have to stick to these workarounds. If you'd rather like to try something new, then go for http://spark-packages.org/package/saurfang/spark-knn

Comment: Actually, step 3 in your answer *is* parallelizable: sklearn’s k-NN kneighbors() method can be distributed with Spark! I've posted how here: https://adventuresindatascience.wordpress.com/2016/04/02/integrating-spark-with-scikit-learn-visualizing-eigenvectors-and-fun/

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 9):

As it happens, I have a solution to this, involving combining sklearn with Spark: https://adventuresindatascience.wordpress.com/2016/04/02/integrating-spark-with-scikit-learn-visualizing-eigenvectors-and-fun/

The gist of it is:

- Use sklearn’s k-NN fit() method centrally
- But then use sklearn’s k-NN kneighbors() method distributedly

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided a lot of detail, but the general approach I would take to this problem would be to:

1. Convert the records to a data structure like like a [LabeledPoint](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint) with (ID, x1..x100) as label and features
2. Map over each record and compare that record to all the other records (lots of room for optimization here)
3. Create some cutoff logic so that once you start comparing ID = 5 with ID = 1 you interrupt the computation because you have already compared ID = 1 with ID = 5
4. Some reduce step to get a data structure like `{id_pair: [1,5], distance: 123}`
5. Another map step to find the 10 closest neighbors of each record

You've identified pyspark and I generally do this type of work using scala, but some pseudo code for each step might look like:

```
# 1. vectorize the features
def vectorize_raw_data(record)
    arr_of_features = record[1..99]
    LabeledPoint( record[0] , arr_of_features)

# 2,3 + 4 map over each record for comparison
broadcast_var = [] 
def calc_distance(record, comparison)
    # here you want to keep a broadcast variable with a list or dictionary of
    # already compared IDs and break if the key pair already exists
    # then, calc the euclidean distance by mapping over the features of
    # the record and subtracting the values then squaring the result, keeping 
    # a running sum of those squares and square rooting that sum
    return {"id_pair" : [1,5], "distance" : 123}    

for record in allRecords:
  for comparison in allRecords:
    broadcast_var.append( calc_distance(record, comparison) )

# 5. map for 10 closest neighbors

def closest_neighbors(record, n=10)
     broadcast_var.filter(x => x.id_pair.include?(record.id) ).takeOrdered(n, distance)
```

The psuedocode is terrible, but I think it communicates the intent. There will be a lot of shuffling and sorting here as you are comparing all records with all other records. IMHO, you want to store the keypair/distance in a central place (like a broadcast variable that gets updated though this is dangerous) to reduce the total euclidean distance calculations you perform.

Answer (score 0):

@xenocyon's blog misses out a lot of information regarding format and usage, I've written a snippet below for better understanding.

```
df = df.withColumn('vector_list', F.array('x1', 'x2', 'x3', ... , 'x100'))
vectors_collected = df.select(df['x1'],df['x2'], ... , df['x100']).rdd.map(list).collect()
knn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=5).fit(vectors_collected)
broadcast_knn = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(knn)
knn_results = df.select(df['vector_list']).rdd.map(lambda x: broadcast_knn.value.kneighbors(x))
```

The below code is to replicate distances and indices similar to sklearn.

```
numpy_knn_results = np.array(knn_results.collect())
# k is 5, hence reshape with 5 each row.
distance = numpy_knn_results.reshape(numpy_knn_results.shape[0]*2, 5)[0::2]
indices = numpy_knn_results.reshape(numpy_knn_results.shape[0]*2, 5)[1::2]
```